# Cannot read properties of null React api json fetch

Tags: reactjs

I'm retrieving data from an API using fetch which I'm storing within the variable 'data'

This is then being mapped to 'character' which I'm adding to my react component

```
</Typography>
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      {data.map((character) => (
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} key={character.id}>
          <Card className={classes.card}>
            <CardMedia
              className={classes.media}
              image={character.image_preview_url}
            />

            <CardContent>
              <Typography color="primary" variant="h5">
                {character.name}
              </Typography>

              <Typography color="textSecondary" variant="subtitle2">
              {character.owner.user.username}
              </Typography>
```

I'm getting the issue on line `{character.owner.user.username}` because not every record in the returned data will contain a value for this item.  How can I set the default to show as "No User" for when the value is returned as NULL ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ternary operator.

It's something like this:

```
<Typography color="textSecondary" variant="subtitle2">
  { character.owner.user.username ? character.owner.user.username : 'No User'}
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could write something like this:

```
{character.owner.user.username ? character.owner.user.username : "No user"}
```